# How do I setup TFS build definition when my localPC, source, build agent, and deployment are all on seperate servers

Tags: build, tfsbuild

I'm trying to set up a build definition in TFS 2010. The options for this seem very limited, for instance I have 5 solution files in my source control and I don't seem to be able to specifiy which one to use. I've selected a workspace from my deployment server (which does a TF get every 10 minutes so I know it's a valid workspace), but when the build runs it gives me an error complaining about the mapping - and it seems to have made it's own mapping up from somewhere.

Mapping I set: `$/InteractV4/Dev/IV4ProductionSR/`

Error: `There is no working folder mapping for $/InteractV4/Dev/IV4Support/iv4ProductionSR.sln.`

There are 2 issues with this error. 1: it's not the workspace I was trying to use. 2: It's wrong and there is a working folder mapping for this source, both on my local PC and on the deployment pc, but NOT on the build server. Do I need to set up a load of folders and mappings on the build agent server? Or on the main TFS (source) server?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you have in the "Get Version" parameter in the build definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS-Builds operate on private Workspaces that get generated during the build process, so using a custom-Workspace is without tweaking impossible.
It's possible to keep TFS from regenerating a new Workspace with each Buid, by going to Build Definition edit "Process":"2.Basic":"Clean Workspace" and changing default value `All` into either `Outputs` or `None`.
The mappings are set for each Build Defition where various pairs exist:

```
Source Control Folder   | Build Agent Folder
$/foo/bar               | $(SourceDir)\somewhere
```

The `$(SourceDir)` is substituted during Build and it gets its value from the Build Agent Settings. If you go to the TFS Admin Console & select "Build Configuration", you 'll be presented with a list of Build Agents running on the Server (there might be additional Agents in other Servers). Clicking on "Properties" of an Agent, pops up a Window like that:
[image]
 This entry "Working directory" is the one that resolves & substitutes `$(SourceDir)` during build.
For example, an entry `$(SystemDrive)\Builds\$(BuildAgentId)` could resolve into something like `C:\Builds\88`.
So, for a TFS Build running on this Agent, you should expect all Sources that stand in source control under `$/foo/bar` to be found under `C:\Builds\88\somewhere`

---

**EDIT**
According to your comments you have now a mapping like this:

```
$\InteractV4\Dev\IV4ProductionSR | $(SourceDir)
```

Your build fails, as "There is no working folder mapping for $/InteractV4/Dev/IV4Support/iv4ProductionSR.sln".
Is this source control directory `$/InteractV4/Dev/IV4Support` mapped in your Build Definition?

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning: There is this button "Copy existing Workspace.." in the 'Workspace' area of the Build Definition editing, which can automatically overtake the mappings of one of your workspaces.

Comment: I used the "Copy existing Workspace" button and copied a workspace from my deployment server. This gave me "$\InteractV4\Dev\IV4ProductionSR" going to "$(SourceDir)". This should have worked? I don't understand where the IV4Support part crept in and why it says there is no workspace if it's supposed to generate itself one?

Comment: "I don't understand where the IV4Support part crept in" >> it's probably required as a ref by one of your items. "why it says there is no workspace" >> please elaborate.

Comment: Ah, in response to your edit I went back and looked more closely and I saw that there is an "items to build" field, which incorrectly had the iv4Support branch in there. I now have an entirely new set of errors, so this is progress, thanks!